# Can I emulate camera flash with Android emulator?

Tags: android

Can I emulate camera flash with Android emulator? I wasn't able to find anything flash-related in the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash is manipulated via camera object  by setting flash mode before taking picture 
or preview.  Emulator will allow you to do this. But I found  flash behaviour extremely inconsistent across different devices.

Real camera applications use undocumented native apis which are specific for phone and camera models.